# mvn spring-boot:build-image failing to execute

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I am on windows 10 machine using WSL2.
Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996
Docker desktop version version 4.22.1
Docker engine is running.

I am trying to build docker image using command mvn spring-boot:build-image.
Here is the build configuration:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>alishahzad93/ccmp-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                    <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I get the following error when I try to execute the goal:

Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.16:build-image (default-cli) on project currency-exchange-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.16:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base/json' failed with status code 404 "Not Found"

Any ideas what might be the issue? Thank you.